# How to Properly Format RetroFit Header for Django

Tags: android, python, django, header, retrofit

I am trying to send an HTTP request using Django that includes a username and password in the header in order to retrieve a token.

On my computer terminal I do the following command and it works properly:

```
http POST 127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/ username='admin' password='whatever'
```

I am trying to do this with Retrofit:

```
@Headers("username=\'admin\' password=\'whatever\'")
@POST("/api-token-auth")
Call<TokenJSON> getToken();
```

However I am presented with the error:

```
@Headers value must be in the form "Name: Value"
```

Is there a correct way to format this header?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are dynamic you can use:

```
Call<TokenJSON> getToken(@Header("username") String var1, @Header("password") String var2);
```

Or if they are static you can use:

```
@Headers({"username: Bar", "password: Pong"})
Call<TokenJSON> getToken();
```

Comment: When I try that it appears to not work as I get 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.jiaohuan.jiaohuan.jsonData.TokenJSON.getToken()' on a null object reference'. This may however be an unrelated error

Comment: is this the same as having "username='admin' password='whatever'"?

Comment: The crash are experiencing seems to be because the web service is not initialized

Comment: I can execute commands fine from my terminal to the server so I know the server is not the issue.

Comment: I meant this part of the code. `new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getUrl())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build().create(clz);`

Comment: Oh no I have that too

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .build();

                service = retrofit.create(UserAPI.class);
                return service;

Comment: I can do GET operations on the server so I know it is not a matter of the connection, but rather the HTTP header's content

Comment: Are you sure the format of the headers are "username: x \n password: y ".  It might be that the http cmd line app is actually sending them as basic auth.

Comment: See that is the thing, it is supposed to be "username='admin' password='whatever'". Notice how it is '=' instead of ':'. I think that is where the problem lies

Comment: run `curl -X POST -H "username: admin" -H "password: whatever" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"` and see if it works. And run `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46d2hhdGV2ZXI=" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"` and see if that works

Comment: When I run the first command I get {"password":["This field is required."],"username":["This field is required."]}, followed with a HTTP 400 error on the server-side